# Выход из приложения как у cleanmaster android

Tags: android

Как реализовать выход из андроид приложения как у клин мастера. После нажатия кнопки back Вылезает Toast "нажмите еще раз для выхода"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
private static long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Нажмите еще раз для выхода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: я тоже уже нашел этот кусок на хабре. спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Писать за вас код не буду, но распишу алгоритм:

1. Создаём булеву переменную `isBackPressed`
2. Переопределяем метод `onBackPressed`
3. В этом методе проверяем, если `!isBackPressed`, то

   3.1. `isBackPressed = true;`
   3.2. Показываем тост "Нажмите ещё раз для выхода"
   3.3. Создаём поток, в нем делаем задержку, равную длительности тоста (для `LENGTH_SHORT` 2000мс, для `LENGTH_LONG` 3500мс)
   3.4. После задержки снова переводим `isBackPressed` в `false`;
4. Иначе выходим из приложения